# Get nonzeros row of a SparseTensor

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I want to get all nonzeros from a row in a SparseTensor so "m" is the sparse tensor object that I have and row is a row I want to get all nonzeros values and indices from. So I want to return an array of the pair that is [(index, values)]. I hope I can get som help on the subject.

```
def nonzeros( m, row):
    res = []
    indices = m.indices
    values = m.values
    userindices = tf.where(tf.equal(indices[:,0], tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64)))
    res = tf.map_fn(lambda index:(indices[index][1], values[index]), userindices)
    return res
```

Error message in terminal

```
TypeError: Input 'strides' of 'StridedSlice' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'begin'.
```

EDIT:
Input for nonzeros
cm is a coo_matrix with values

```
m = tf.SparseTensor(indices=np.array([row,col]).T,
                        values=cm.data,
                        dense_shape=[10, 10])
nonzeros(m, 1)
```

if the data is

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

result should be

```
[index, value]
[4,1]
[9,2]
```

Comment: Could you please report an input-output example? In this way we can better understand how to obtain what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `index` inside the lambda is a Tensor and you can't use that directly to index into e.g. `indices`. You could use `tf.gather` instead. Also, you didn't make use of the `row` parameter in the code you posted.

Try this instead:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def nonzeros(m, row):
    indices = m.indices
    values = m.values
    userindices = tf.where(tf.equal(indices[:, 0], row))
    found_idx = tf.gather(indices, userindices)[:, 0, 1]
    found_vals = tf.gather(values, userindices)[:, 0:1]
    res = tf.concat(1, [tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(found_idx, tf.float64), -1), found_vals])
    return res

data = np.array([[0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
                [0., 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.]])

m = tf.SparseTensor(indices=np.array([[0, 1], [0, 9], [1, 4], [1, 9]]),
                    values=np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]),
                    shape=[2, 10])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = nonzeros(m, 1)
    print(sess.run(result))
```

which prints:

```
[[ 4.  1.]
 [ 9.  2.]]
```